# .profile in Ubuntu is running desired Python script, but script is not working as usual?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gsettings

I'm creating a background changer for Ubuntu using Python, mostly for fun. When I run the script from the shell, it works and alternates the background between images in a certain folder. Now I am trying to run the script through .profile so that it runs upon login. The script is definitely running--I put a print statment in the relevant function, and when I hit 'alt, ctrl, f3', I see the output of the print statement--but for whatever reason, the background will not change when the function is called this way. I don't think it's a matter of running it from a non-local directory, either--as I said, if I run 'python program/python/desktop_changer/main.py', the desktop changer runs just fine.

Here are the relevant parts of the function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(15)
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    while True:

    #Set pic, set timer, run continously
    for img in os.listdir('pics/'):
        #This next line is functional when I hit 'alt, ctrl, f3', outputting the paths for new images every ten seconds
        print(os.path.abspath('pics/' + img))
        set_gnome_wallpaper(os.path.abspath('pics/' + img))
        time.sleep(float(10))
```

And set_gnome_wallpaper():

```
def set_gnome_wallpaper(file_path):
    command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom' && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://'%s'" % file_path
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

And in ~/.profile: (SPE and 20 are irrelevant arguments and their uses are commented out until I can get this running correctly)

```
python /home/chessie/program/python/desktop_changer/main.py SPE 20 &
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `&` from the command in `.profile`?

Comment: Please make sure the indentation of your Python programs is correct. Hint: Paste in your script, then select the pasted script and type ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Is your Gnome desktop running when your shell starts up?  What happens when you start additional shell instances?

Comment: @trileee indentation is correct in the program, StackOverflow is just new to me. Thanks, I'll fix it. Also, no shell is appears when I login. If I start additional shells, they work normally (nothing changed from when the program isn't running).

Comment: @MadPhysicist If I remove the &, the program will prevent me from logging in properly until I use 'ctrl, alt, f3' and cancel the command.

Comment: Makes sense. I notice you still haven't fixed your indentation for `set_gnome_wallpaper`.

Comment: And the `while True:` is still lacking indentation inside the block.  We can probably guess where to indent and unindent but having to guess makes troubleshooting less worth our while.